# Google picks wrong canonical url in search results

Tags: google-search, canonical-url

When I do a search in google I receive results as expected. When I hover over the search result I can see the correct url. But when I click on it I'm redirected to the homepage. In the search console I find the page not being indexed + google is choosing a different canonical url (homepage) then what is coded in the meta-data. What can I do to solve this? And make google choose the canonical url I indicated.

Comment: This has been an ongoing issue for over a month now.  You're not alone in this.  https://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-canonical-url-issues-30180.html

Comment: If you were being redirected to your homepage that could be a problem on your site not on Google.